# nodal precession: earth's orbit of sun

Tags: orbit, precession

Does the Earth's orbit around the sun exhibit nodal precession, as does the moon's around the Earth?  If it does, that must mean that the ecliptic is in a periodic wobble with respect to the celestial sphere?

Comment: The ecliptic *is* in periodic wobble wrt the celestial sphere, but that's because of nutation, not precession. *Precession* (nodal precession) changes where the Sun is during the equinoxes and solstices. The Spring Equinox, for example, has moved from Aries (it's still called "the first point of Aries") to near the Taurus-Gemini border.

Comment: Done, though I don't think my comment was answer-worthy and definitely not bounty-worthy, but, hey, since you posted the bounty...

Comment: @Barrycarter, the first point of Aries is now in Pisces.

Comment: @DrChuck How embarrassing. You are correct, of course, and it is moving towards Aquarius ("the age of Aquarius"). I meant the summer solstice of course. I will feel bad about myself for the next 6 hours as penance.

Comment: @barrycarter Hope you are feeling better now.

Comment: Using Wikipedia as a reference, nodal precession can be calculated based on an object's equatorial bulge and the variation of the Earth's orbital plane to the sun's equatorial plane (ecliptic).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession#Equation   I'd prefer not to try to do the math myself though.

Answer (score 1):

The ecliptic is in periodic wobble wrt the celestial sphere, but that's because of nutation, not precession. Precession (nodal precession) changes where the Sun is during the equinoxes and solstices. The Spring Equinox, for example, has moved from Aries (it's still called "the first point of Aries") to near the Pisces-Aquarius border

Comment: I am aware of the nutation in Earth's axial tilt...same thing you mention? Let me ask differently: the lunar orbit around Earth exhibits westward precession (the nodes rotate around the ecliptic plane.) Kind of like a coin spinning on a table.  Does the Earth's orbit of the Sun do basically the same thing, two other motions being eccentricity chg and apsidal precession?

Comment: also I have read a figure of 70,000 yrs as the periodic cycle of the "nodal precession" I'm trying to understand, if that helps.

Comment: @kathyslover OK, I think you're talking about "apsidal precession" which is described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsidal_precession -- however, the 70,000 year number appears only on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milankovitch_cycles#Orbital_inclination

Comment: Can you help me understand better; are you answering *yes* or *no* to the first part of the question "Does the Earth's orbit around the sun exhibit nodal precession?" Also it sure looks like you are talking about nodal precession of the Earth's axis. The question is about the nodal precession of the *Earth's orbit*. Can you first clearly address issues of the Earth's orbit, and put discussion of the Earth's axis perhaps in a separate paragraph so that they don't get mixed up? Just saying nodal precession without specifying *of what* makes this answer difficult to understand.

Comment: @uhoh I agree: my answer is wrong for the reasons you state. It's only in the comments that I get it right. I'll try to fix my answer, but feel free to edit if you'd like. I'm also not sure I fully understand apsidal precession (Stellarium doesn't appear to model it), so my only real answer is the link I give in the comments.

Comment: @barrycarter This is a really good and not-so-easy question actually! The sun does have a tiny $J_2$ (order of 1E-07 when expressed as a dimensionless quantity, see [For the mathematical relationship between J2 with units and without units - which one is derived from the other?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22976/12102)), but that plus the huge distance means the effect will be very very weak.

Comment: @uhoh If the animation on the wikipedia page is accurate and Earth's apsidal precession period is 70K years, it would mean the ecliptic would be very different in, say, 20K years, but Stellarium doesn't appear to show that (of course, it could be wrong, don't think you're supposed to use it past 10000 CE).

Comment: @barrycarter the question is about precession of the ascending and descending nodes; the intersection points between the Sun's equatorial plane and the Earth's orbit. (The effect is due to the equatorial bulge of the Sun). Moving the nodes will change the ecliptic as seen from the Earth. But precession of the apses (periapsis and apoapsis) only have to do with the Earth being slightly closer or slightly farther from the Sun. Unless I'm totally confused, *apsidal precession of the Earth's orbit does not change the plane of the orbit or (to first order at least) the appearance of the ecliptic*.